# How to deactivate USB power management for every device per batch/periodically?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, power-management, control-panel

In "Control Panel" → "System" → "Device Manager" → "Universal Serial Bus Controllers", it is possible to deactivate "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" within "Power Management". 
This is present in Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 7, etc.

I need this deactivated for all USB devices (all the time),
but it is activated for new ones.

Is there a Windows control panel, command, registry setting or other interface
that turns these off (all at once, not requiring me to set each one),
and/or monitors them if some device pops up where this is not deactivated
or deactivates again if it becomes active for some reason?